# Start vpnc at boot time on Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS

Tags: vpnc

How can I start vpnc at boot time on Ubuntu 16.04 server (no GUI)? 
Starting manually works but at every reboot I must login and start the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it at boot time put the command in `/etc/rc.local` using the command `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and, after entering password, just put the bash command to start vpnc just before the 'exit 0' at the end of the file.

Additionally, if you see it doesn't work correctly you may want to put it in files like `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`. FYI: bash_profile is read first but if you already have one of them created with some content in it you may want to use that. This would run the command when you login, just in case you want that.